# The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null via loading Grid View

Tags: c#

While loading DataGridView, I'm getting the following error:

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

I tried this:

```
public static void LoadPaymentGridView1(DataGridView grid)
{
    try
    {
        var load = dbcontext.SupplierStatementTable.OrderByDescending(s => s.PaymentID).Select(s => new
        {
            ID = s.SupplierPaymentTable.ID,
            Supplier=s.SupplierPaymentTable.SupplierRegistrationTable.Name,
            PreBalance=s.PreBalance,
            Payment=s.Payment,
            Date=s.SupplierPaymentTable.Date
        }).ToList();
        grid.DataSource = load;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `DataGridView` definition, the error indicates that you're trying to set an `Int32` value to `null`, which is not allowed.

With your .Select you're creating a new Anonymous Type with those 5 properties, and then I assume attempting to map them to what your grid is expecting. The Anonymous Type has no issues with one of the 5 properties being set to `null` because it has no specified types, but when it attempts to load those into the grid it ends up trying to write what it believes is something like an `Int32?` into an `Int32` and throws the error.

To get around this you need to handle the `null` value. Either change the definition in your `DataGridView` to be an `Int32?` (allowing null values), or change the `.Select` to detect a `null` value and set a default - perhaps with a null coalescing operator `??` - assuming ID is the problem property:

```
.Select(s => new
{
     ID = s.SupplierPaymentTable.ID ?? 0,
     Supplier=s.SupplierPaymentTable.SupplierRegistrationTable.Name,
     PreBalance=s.PreBalance,
     Payment=s.Payment,
     Date=s.SupplierPaymentTable.Date
})
```

---

Per your comment below - accessing data from the related DbSets requires that you've got your models set up properly. The code you commented below, formatted:

```
var load = dbcontext.SupplierPaymentTable
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.ID)
            .Select(s => new 
                    { ID = s.ID, 
                     Supplier=s.SupplierRegistrationTable.Name, 
                     PreBalance=s.SupplierStatementTable.prebalance, 
                     Payment=s.Payment, 
                     Balance=s.?????, 
                     Date=s.????? ,
                     UserName=s.UserName 
                    })
            .ToList(); 
grid.DataSource = load;
```

In the `.Select` here, `s` represents an object stored in the `SupplierPaymentTable` DbSet, i.e.:

```
public DbSet<SupplierPayment> SupplierPaymentTable{ get; set; }
```

(s represents a `SupplierPayment`)

To access properties on the `SupplierStatementTable` DbSet *through* from this, you need to have a 'foreign key' style reference in the DbSet Model definition. To meet the two references you've made in your example, I'd expect the model used for `dbcontext.SupplierPaymentTable` to include at least these two properties:

```
public class SupplierPayment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public SupplierPayment SupplierPayment {get; set;}
    public SupplierStatement SupplierStatement {get; set;}
    public double Payment {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
}
```

Without seeing how your DBContext is fully defined I can't really give you anything else - but it should just be a matter of tracing through your relationships and making sure they're all working as intended.

Comment: hey bro i got the error but now i faced another error:
i cant access supplierStatementTable from SupplierPaymentTable event the RelationShip is also ok
the following is the code i wrote
" var load = dbcontext.SupplierPaymentTable.OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).Select(s => new
{
ID = s.ID,
Supplier=s.SupplierRegistrationTable.Name,
PreBalance=s.SupplierStatementTable.prebalance,
Payment=s.Payment,
Balance=s.?????,
Date=s.?????
UserName=s.UserName
}).ToList();
grid.DataSource = load;

Comment: Kayndarr bro plz

Comment: @KhalilTaskeen See edits above. If you're still having issues with the Entity Framework relationships I'd recommend asking a separate question as it's a different problem to the basis of this question.